# When writing jQuery, what leads to better performance?

Tags: jquery

When writing `jQuery`, what leads to better performance?

- Reference items directly via their `id/class` each time i.e
  `$('#myDiv')`
- Save useful `jQuery` selectors as variables and reuse these i.e `var
  myDiv = $('#myDiv')`
- Traverse the tree from a specific point using `prev() next()
  find() closest()` etc

Comment: They aren't mutually exclusive, use each technique when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the situation, but as you state, it is (usually) a good idea to 'cache' your selectors. There's also a lot of behind-the-scenes mechanics, that could help you out - Such as using `$("#id").find(".subchild")` instead of `$("#id .subchild")`, since using only a id selector, uses the browsers internal 'find-element-with-this-id' engine.

Have a look at https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/ - It really explains a lot on how to speed up some things :)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on reusing a selector multiple times then it's a good idea to cache them in a variable to avoid expensive DOM lookup each time.